# Use two different Axios Request functions in another function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, node-modules

How can I call two different Axios functions in another function? The second function can only be called or implemented if the first one is successful and returns a 200.

**`functions.js` has the two functions that would be exported to be used in the `server.js`** **The Body of the request is imported from a json file.**

`functions.js`

```
const axios = require("axios");
const BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8880";
const body = require("./payload.json");


** I want the `postSchedule` function to return the response data if the response status is 200, but currently I get a bad request error message.** 

const postSchedule = async () => {
  const headers = {
    "BKK-API-Version": "v2",
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  };
  const payload = body;
  try {
    const resp = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/schedule`, { headers }, payload);
    const data = resp.data;
    if (!data) {
      throw "failed to successfully send Schedule";
    }

    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    console.log(err);
  }
};



***For the `triggerSchedule` function, how can I make the id dynamic? I want the id to be whatever the user puts on postman. I know in express, it's `const id = req.params`.**

const triggerSchedule = async () => {
    
      let id = $id
    
  const headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  };
  
    try {
        const resp = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/schedule` + id, {headers})
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("Your schedule has been successfully triggered", response.data);
      }
        return (response.data);
      }catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
}
module.exports = {
  triggerSchedule,
  postSchedule,
};
```

`server.js` imports `functions.js` file to be used in the new function `implementScheduling`, which is called in `app.get(/schedule` route.

**`server.js`**

```
// dependenices
const express = require("express");
const schedules = require("./function.js");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const PORT = 8000;
app.use(express.json());

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Running this application on the PORT ${PORT}`);
});

const implementScheduling =() => {
//code
}
app.get("/schedule", implementScheduling());
```

**`in the frontend, when a user clicks on a button, a request is sent to` localhost:8000/app`and technically`implementScheduling `is called. How can I efficiently write my backend functions and promise, so that the frontend axios function can have their own custom errors and logics?`**

const setSchedule = () => {
const body = payload;

```
axios
  .post("http://localhost:8000/schedule", body)
  .then((resp) => {
    const data = resp.data;
    saveSchedule(scheduleResponse, data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

};

Answer (score 1):

**Hi Tini,**

*Thanks for your question!!*

This is my proposal aligned with some good practices you can follow based on: scaffolding, layers, patterns and clean code. With this you can scale, mantain and control your code.

> You will have many ways to approach your issue.

This proposal is aligned to your code styling.

**-------------SCAFFOLDING-------------**

Change your current folder and files organization.

**SCAFFOLDING/FRONTEND-----**

For scaffolding you can follow MVC, MVVM MV**M, MCS, MCS, etc..
*Following the ***View Controller Service (VCS)*** layer pattern *(This is an idea based on my experience)**

Is important to separate service layer from common HTTP handler calling, like axio, multer, etc...

***common/config.js***

Here you should add a list of constant like functions and object; for url, setup, default values, all related to HTTP setups. You can add constant for other common setup values, like navigation, initial values, etc..

```
export const API = {
  server: "http://localhost:8000",
  headers: {
    "BKK-API-Version": "v2",
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  }
  ...
}
```

***common/apiUrl.js***

Here you should add a list of constant object related to endpoint url

```
import { API } from "../common/config";

export const SCHEDULE = {
  all: `${API.server}/schedule`,
  add: `${API.server}/schedule`,
  update:`${API.server}/schedule/:id`,
  updateWithPar: `${API.server}/schedule`,
  ...
}
```

***services/HTTP.js***

In this file or class you can add all the HTTP verbs async functions for the *HTTP/API* endpoint calling. Here you can implement axios, or multer or any other http calling lib.

```
import http from "axios";

export const AXIOS = (url, method, data, params) => axios({
  method,
  url,
  data,
  params
});
```

The advantage of this, is

- Add flexibility to scalling. If tomorrow you want to switch from Axios lib to any other, you do not have to change all your code api axio calling implementation. You only have to change it in one place.
- Easy to test
- Easy to mock
- and other more...

***services/scheduleSvc.js***

In this file or class you can add all the async functions for the *HTTP/API* schedule endpoints calling.
I add a ***suffix "'name'Svc"*** term in the file name, to know that this file is related to a service. But this is optional, you can add yours.

```
import API from "./HTTP";
import { SCHEDULE } from "../common/apiUrl";

export const listOfSchedules = async () => await API(SCHEDULE.all, "get");

export const add = async (data) => await API(SCHEDULE.add, "post", data);

export const update = async (data, id) => await API(SCHEDULE.update.replace(":id", id), "post", data);
```

In this case, you can send the id as part of the url. If you want to send if as parameter in the header you can add this approache:

```
export const update = async (data, params) => await API(SCHEDULE.update, "post", data, params);
```

In the ***add*** or ***update*** method you can replace the ***data*** function parameter with the payload.json file

***pages/schedule.js***

Here you should add the react ui calling. Should be a container or page structure implementation.

```
import React from "react";
import { add, update } from "../../services/scheduleSvc";

const schedulePG = () => {
  
  const addHandler = () => {...} // calling of add service
  const updateHandler = () => {...} // calling of update service, send the params object: e.g; const params = { id: 233 }...
  
  return (...)
}
```

**SCAFFOLDING/BACKEND-----**

***server.js***

You can your Express server setup, CORS config, your endpoint registration, and others stuff.

**-------------APPROACHES-------------**

Having all your code well orgnanized, will be more easy to add approaches or features.

**GLOBAL-----**

Implement any dinamic Type language or lib like TYPESCRIPT, FLOW, TYPE, etc...
This will give you some advantage

- Implementation of type, interface and other good practices
- Secure and robust code.
- etc..

**FRONTEND-----**

***Handling any API/ENDPOINT error***

*Implement Axios Interceptor*

How you've implemented ***Axios***, this lib has an ***Interceptor*** implementation.

So in the ***HTTP.js*** file where you have the calling of the axios you can set the request - response success and error handling. This can work for common error for any page.

> Combinating this with any redux or flux implementation you can
> capture, send and display to the user UI any custom or general
> response.

This fragment of code example is toke from the [Axios package site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  // Do something before request is sent
  return config;
}, function (error) {
  // Do something with request error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
  // Any status code that lie within the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
  // Do something with response data
  return response;
}, function (error) {
  // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
  // Do something with response error
  return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

*Customize your own Error Handler*

If you want t0 add a specific or custom error for an specific page or service. You should take a moment and think about the architecture beside having and axios/interceptor, redux/middleware in case you're using redux, notification lib, error interception and the User Experience related to this. Theres is no specific solution, this will depends on your necesity, app nature, and other stuff you have to consider.

I'll suggest you to create a ***Notification Service*** layer, so this class can receive a code and any custom text and works kind of a middleware. So It can capture the error and know which message can be displayed to the UI.

This way you can separate the calling of the service and the handling error responsibility, following SOLID and SINGLE RESPONSIBILITY principles.

Remember in the Express/Nodejs server calling, to return a clear error structure. Do not retur the default server error, customize your response/ERROR and response/SUCCESS structure.

```
{
  code: --code--,
  text: "",
}
```

**BACKEND-----**

For retrieve the params use the ***Express `request.params` method***

---

I hope this work for you.
Any help you can send a DM message.

If you found any other approach, please share it as a comment, so we can have a continue improovement.

Regards.