# Call or merge two individual API Request functions in a new Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, async-await, axios

How can I call two different individual functions -`postStudent` and `triggerScoring`- in a new function? Here's my use case:

`postStudent` has to run first. It returns an id as its `resp.data`.  That `id` is what I need to set/pass as the `id` of the Post request in `triggerScoring`.

So what I want to do is create a new function that would:

- call `postStudent` and wait for it to run and return its response. The expected response is an id.
- If the request is a success and the id is returned, grab and save the id to a variable.
- pass the saved id as the param in `triggerScoring`, and then call the `triggerScoring` function.
- finally return a success message if both functions successfully run and is completed.

How can I implement this? using Async await? The new function can be called `mergeFunctions`:

**student.js**

```
const BASE_URL = htttp://localhost:3000

const postStudent = async (req, res, next) => {
  const headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
  };
  const body = { name: 'Adam Lawrence' };
  try {
    const resp = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/student`, body, { headers });
    const response = resp.data;
    res.send(response);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response) {
      res.status(err.response.status).send(err.response.data);
    } else if (err.request) {
      res.send(err.request);
    }
    next(err);
  }
};


const triggerScoring = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { id } = 
  const headers = {
    "Score-API-Version": "v2",
  };
  try {
    const resp = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/start/${id}`, { headers });
    const response = resp.data;
    res.send(response);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.response) {
      res.status(err.response.status).send(err.response.data);
    } else if (err.request) {
      res.send(err.request);
    }
    next(err);
  }
};
```

**new function**

Comment: Do you use express.js? If you use express.js and use new function for routing, you can use middleware!

Comment: Hi Didi,

You can take a look at the answer of this question similar to your one. 
Its gives you an idea, path and tips for an implementation

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74740452/3859088

I hope its help you
Regards

Comment: @boykland I did. The answer is confusing to me.

Comment: Hi Didi, we can have a one o one live coding, if you want. So we can reach to a solution.